# How can i put my pagination to work properly in a searching result using keyup event?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am using keyup() function to send the variable to a php page (consult.php) that has the mysql select to bring my search result.

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 $('#input').keyup(function(){
  var inputVal=$('#input').val();
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   data: ({word : inputVal}),
   url: 'consult.php',
   success: function(data) {
    $('#content').html(data);
   }
  });
 });
 $("#menu li").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   data: ({word : inputVal}),
   url: 'consult.php',
   success: function(data) {
    $('#content').html(data);
  }
  });
 });
});
</script>
<style>
 #menu ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
 }
 #menu ul li{
  padding:5px;
  margin-right:2px;
  float:left;
  border:#00F solid 1px;
  background-color:#faa8ad;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div>Write<br>
  <input type="text" id="input" name="input"/>
 </div>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

consult.php

```
<?
 include('conn.php');
 $word = isset($_POST['word']) ? $_POST['word'] : $_GET['word'];
 if($word){

  $perPag = 4;
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(carro_id) FROM carros WHERE carro_modelo LIKE '$word%'");
  $totalResult = ceil(mysql_result($query, 0)/$perPag);

  $pag = (isset($_GET['pag']) and (int)$_GET['pag'] > 0) ? (int)$_GET['pag'] : 1;
  $ini = ($pag - 1) * $perPag;

  $queryTotal = mysql_query("SELECT carro_modelo FROM carros WHERE carro_modelo LIKE '$word%' ORDER BY carro_id LIMIT $ini, $perPag");
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryTotal)){
       echo "<div>".$row['carro_modelo']."</div>";
      }
  if($totalResult >= 1 && $pag <= $totalResult){
   for($i = 1; $i <= $totalResult; $i++){
    echo($i == $pag) ? '<div id="menu"><ul><li><strong><a href="?pag='.$i.'&word='.$word.'">'.$i.'</a></strong></li></ul></div> ' : '<div id="menu"><ul><li><a href="?pag='.$i.'&word='.$word.'">'.$i.'</a></li></ul></div> ';
   }
  }
 }else{
  $queryTotalReult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM carros");
  while($rowTotal = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryTotalReult)){
   echo "<div>".$rowTotal['carro_modelo']."</div>";
  }
 }
?>
```

The problem is, when i click in the links of the pagination its load back the result in the index.php bringing all results again ignoring the search.

thank you in advance!

Comment: you have to post all the needed parameters when page submit and change the query with search keyword and pagination params or use ajax pagination

Comment: thanks for ur help, u mean instead use GET use POST? could you please give me a example how can i make this changes? i appreciate a lot

Comment: I posted code below that likely works, but I strongly recommend looking into what's going on here.  It's better to actually learn how to do it than to just try what you're told.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function ajaxCall(inPage,inWord)
{

      $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       data: ({word : inWord, pag : inPage}),
       url: 'consult.php',
       success: function(data) {
        $('#content').html(data);
       }});
}
    $(function(){
     $('#input').keyup(function(){
      var inputVal=$('#input').val();
      $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       data: ({word : inputVal}),
       url: 'consult.php',
       success: function(data) {
        $('#content').html(data);
       }
      });
     });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
     #menu ul{
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      list-style:none;
     }
     #menu ul li{
      padding:5px;
      margin-right:2px;
      float:left;
      border:#00F solid 1px;
      background-color:#faa8ad;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div>Write<br>
      <input type="text" id="input" name="input"/>
     </div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

consult.php

```
<?
 include('conn.php');
 $word = isset($_POST['word']) ? $_POST['word'] : $_GET['word'];
 if($word){
  $perPag = 4;
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(carro_id) FROM carros WHERE carro_modelo LIKE '$word%'");
  $totalResult = ceil(mysql_result($query, 0)/$perPag);
  $pag = (isset($_GET['pag']) and (int)$_GET['pag'] > 0) ? (int)$_GET['pag'] : 1;
  $ini = ($pag - 1) * $perPag;
  $queryTotal = mysql_query("SELECT carro_modelo FROM carros WHERE carro_modelo LIKE '$word%' ORDER BY carro_id LIMIT $ini, $perPag");
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryTotal)){
       echo "<div>".$row['carro_modelo']."</div>";
      }
  if($totalResult >= 1 && $pag <= $totalResult){
   for($i = 1; $i <= $totalResult; $i++){
    echo($i == $pag) ? '<div id="menu"><ul><li><strong><a onclick="ajaxCall('.$i.',\''.$word.'\')">'.$i.'</a></strong></li></ul></div> ' : '<div id="menu"><ul><li><a onclick="ajaxCall('.$i.',\''.$word.'\')">'.$i.'</a></li></ul></div> ';
   }
  }
 }else{
  $queryTotalReult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM carros");
  while($rowTotal = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryTotalReult)){
   echo "<div>".$rowTotal['carro_modelo']."</div>";
  }
 }
?>
```

Comment: when i click in 2 at the pagination the result disappears

Comment: Oh, yeah, you'll need to attach a click event to that to make the same AJAX call as your keyup event.  So, instead of it linking somewhere, it should call a Javascript function which will pull the records, same as you have for keyup.

Comment: i tried put the click event after outside of keyup event:
`$("#menu li").click(function(){ the same ajax code here });`
didnt work!

Comment: I see you've done it recently, but could you update your code again in your original post to reflect exactly what you are working with currently?

Comment: I updated mine as well.  Try my two files too and see if it helps at all.

Comment: The pagination is not clickable anymore

Comment: You won't have a click cursor but you should still be able to click it and it should still update your results.

Comment: I inserted the `cursor:pointer;` in my css style, and still not clickable

Comment: Could you give me a link to where you are testing this?

Comment: Is there a remote server you could transfer this all to?  I'd like to get a look at the HTML rendering.

Comment: I didnt configure a remote server yet i am using MAMP not for long time. Still in a standard configuration

Comment: Is it easy to set up the remote server? if yes i can do it

Comment: Could you open your page and view the source and paste that here so that I can see what you're seeing?

Comment: the index.php: `view-source:http://localhost:8888/keyup/` is the same as what is in the post

Comment: I can't actually see localhost.  Localhost is available from your computer only.

Comment: yep i know. ;) i just wanted to show you that i went to the view-source from chrome browser and it showed me the same as it is in the post

Comment: Type in a search so that you get results, then view the source.  It should now show you the HTML for the data and the pages.  That's what I want to see.

Comment: no! It doesnt shows.. i put this external ip to listen my config. try to access it please: `http://213.22. 220.10:8888/keyup/`

Comment: http://213.22.220.10/keyup not found and http://213.22.220.10:8888/keyup doesn't work but I think we're getting close.

Comment: i made a change to the listen, could you please try again?

Comment: http://213.22.220.10/keyup not found and :8888/keyup looks like it does a redirect or something maybe but doesn't work.

Comment: u think we're getting close? have u see any other way to solve it?

Comment: if you put this `echo "i: ".$i, "pag: ".$pag;` inside of the for statement, you will see that for page 2 $i is different than $pag. And change onclick for onClick, in the same line i think u have to put " after ). `<a onClick="ajaxCall('.$i.',\''.$word.'\')">`

Comment: Ok @dweiss i really want to thank you for ur help! I will try another way to do what i want unfortunately.. thank you i dont want to waste more time from you. cheers man

Comment: got the solution, i changed the type of ur ajax code to GET. And woo hoo.. thats it! Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

In your query you have $initial, but in the assignment you have $ini.  Maybe try making these the same :)

Comment: Also, in the next/back links you need to pass word again, and you'll need to check for $_GET['word'] in the php backend as well.

Comment: thanks for correcting me, but this wasnt the problem. ;)
sry but i didnt get what you mean next/back? based in my code could you make me an example please? the consult.php is the same as the index.php, the only change is that instead of bring all results i bring only what is typed inside the input field

Comment: Pages: 1, 2, 3, 4 <-- for the link for each one of these, you have pag= but you also need word= so: http://google.com/?page=2&word=search_here

Comment: <strong><a href="?pag='.$i.'&word='.$word.'">'.$i.'</a></strong> and you also need to check isset($_POST['word']) or isset($_GET['word']) because now you will be submitting word via get on these link clicks.

Comment: Nah, you've got ?pagina=$i but you also need &word=$word

Comment: oh yeah.. i havent think like that.. one moment i will try this

Comment: well, sry now i got confused. I never used this "&" inside of the url before. So when i put some word in the input, my url now look like this: ?pag=1&word=$word

Comment: No problem, Andre!  Basically, you're trying to pass parameters from one page to the next via a method called GET.  You use ? to denote parameters, but for every parameter after the first you will use &. http://www.google.com/?param1=val1&param2=val2&param3=val3.  Check out the wiki to learn more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string.  I think if you paste all of your code here I'll be able to give you some more help!

Comment: i changed the javascript to pass the variable as a GET instead of POST and set the url like u said, but still the same, when i click in the pagination of the search it goes back to the index.php but the curious is the url change to: `?pag=2&word=c` but the link dont correspond the search

Comment: Yep updated it! Had to translate some words! and i put the javascript inside of index page, it was in another page with others scripts that i use in others things. And also i have put back the code that i made

Comment: echo($i == $pag) ? '<strong><a href="?pag='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></strong> ' : '<a href="?pag='.$i.'&word='.$word.'">'.$i.'</a> '; <-- change your code to this line here.  Also: 
 $word = isset($_POST['word'] ? $_POST['word'] : $_GET['word'];

Comment: u mean change it in consult.php or index.php?
in consult.php i already have a variable called $word receiving the POST: `$word = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['word']);`

Comment: Yeah, change that line that you have where you assign $word to $word = isset($_POST['word'] ? $_POST['word'] : $_GET['word'];.  Also change the other line like I mentioned in the last post.

Comment: Still the same! When i search it goes right, like was. But when i click in the pagination e.g. (when i click in number 2) it goes to number 2 of index.php not the number 2 of the list searched. And the page url changes to this: `?pag=2&word=c`

Comment: I updated the post, put some pics for you to see what is happening!

Comment: ?pag=2&word=c is good actually, and your screenshots look like they might be accurate? ?pag=2&word=c simply means that it's sending that data back to your PHP page, c is your search and 2 is the current page.

Comment: When i click in 2 of the pagination in the search result, it should come the next 4 results with c. But it is coming the 4 next result of the total results in this table in DB

Comment: Could you remove your consult.php and show it again please?  The URL looks good now, so it must be something in consult.php.

Comment: sry didnt get you, remove from where?

Comment: I need to see your latest version of consult.php

Comment: My last version is there in the post. The pics was taken after put the changes u said. I didnt change the code in the post!

Comment: Honestly?  I'm a bit confused.  I don't really understand why you have two files and why they both seem to have the same code.  And I don't see the word= in either of the files, but it does show in your output, so I don't think you have the latest version of your files shown here.  I'd love to help you out more but it's getting a little difficult.

Comment: what u recommend me to do? i just want to make it work.. can i make it in one page only? It not have to be like this, if u show me how  make it work in one page its fine for me

Comment: In case you somehow have missed it, I posted a possible solution as another answer.